# SP13: Link to Page on SharePoint Banner

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, master-page, hyperlink

I am not sure this is possible.  Is there a way to make the SharePoint that appears in the upper-left hand corner to be linkable?  I want users to be able to click on "SharePoint" and take them to a site collection home page.  Is this possible?  If so how can this be done?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if there's a way to do it out of the box, you would need to add a script to all pages (custom action) to switch it to a hyperlink.

Comment: You should be able to as you can change the text.  The div for it should be ms-core-brandingText

Comment: @FlatBanana wouldn't ms-core-brandingText just change the text and not allowing to add a hyperlink to the page?

Comment: .ms-core-brandingText{href:www.google.com}</style>   Do you think this could work?

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work, there is no property called href in CSS , so you should use JS as I have mentioned in my answer that tried on my side and working properly, hope it help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the following code in a script editor that working properly.

```
<script>
function doredirect() {
//var x = document.getElementById("suiteBarLeft");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-core-brandingText");
x[0].onclick = doaction;
x[0].style.cursor='pointer';
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("doredirect");

function doaction()
{
window.location.href="http://Qassas";
}
</script>
```

**To apply it to all pages, you can do**

- [AdditionalPageHead delegate control, or](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls/)
- [Custom Action](http://www.jbmurphy.com/2012/02/10/how-add-custom-javascript-code-to-all-sharepoint-2010-pages-customaction/) , or
- Just edit your master page and paste the above code below `</body>` (tried also from my side)

Answer (score 2):

No need to Javascript.... You could simply edit your masterpage (it's what I did wiht mine).
Search for :

```
<div class="ms-core-brandingText">SharePoint</div>
```

And change to:

```
<a href="/" title="Go to Homepage" class="ms-core-brandingText">Name of your website</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript or Master Page customisation to change the behaviour fo this SharePoint Branding text. 
It's a property of the web application and can be set web application wide.

`$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://tozit-sp:2015
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "Awesome Text Goes Here" 
$webApp.Update()`

Source: [SP 2013: Tip - Change the "SharePoint" text in the top left corner.](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-tip-change-the-sharepoint-text-in-the-top-left-corner/)

You will finde more detailed information at the source.

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript, try below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector(".ms-core-brandingText").addEventListener('click',function(){
    window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; //change url as per your requirement
 },false)
</script>
```

If you are using jQuery, you can try below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.ms-core-brandingText").click(
function()
{
    window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; //change url as per your requirement
    return false;
});
</script>
```

You can add the code in masterpage just above the `</body>` tag if you want it across the site collection. If you want it on specific pages, add in the respective page layouts or add script editor webpart on the page.